# Printer driver for Konical Minolta Magicolor 1600W?

Tags: drivers, printing

I have a new printer and found the proper driver for it when I am using Windows, but I work under Ubuntu most of the time and the system does not recognize the printer.

Is there away to install a generic printer that makes it possible for me to use this while I am under Ubuntu? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits. Color is not important, as long as I can print my documents, I am OK. I can use Windows for color printing.

Thanks in advance,
Farhad

Comment: Well, my printer died shortly after this so I didn't have a chance to test it out, the thing I learned from the whole Minolta affair is that NEVER buy products from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the driver which works on all our printers. The driver is **ljet4** , just found some similar model of printer with **ljet4** sufix on name and it will work. I wrote more on my blog : http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2013/01/driver-that-works-on-allmost-all.html

We tried on KONICA MINOLTA 24f and c353 and man from KONICA MINOLTA told as that every printer he tried works with those drivers.. so your printer should work also.